# Compare saved entities

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Im saving some entities, which I get from a REST-API. Im using the Spring JPA repos for that. Im generating an id for every entity when saving. The sanveAndFlush() Method does only watch if the id of the entity is already there and then it wouldnt save it again. But my problem is, that I generate i id and then it just duplicates the entities when saving. How can i compare with something other of the entity like the text or something likte this.

Housekeeping Service:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(Tweetpost tweetpost) {
        tweetRepository.saveAndFlush(tweetpost);
    }
```

Tweetpost Entity:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(columnDefinition = "INT unsigned")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONG")
    private long tweetid;

    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 255)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String profileImageUrl;

    @NotEmpty
    @Length(max = 64)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(64)", length = 64, nullable = false)
    private String fromUser;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT", nullable = false)
    private String unmodifiedText;

    @NotNull
    @Column(columnDefinition = "DATE", nullable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Length(max = 255)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String url;

    @Length(max = 255)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String displayUrl;

    @Length(max = 255)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String expandedUrl;

    @Length(max = 255)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(255)", length = 255, nullable = false)
    private String mediaUrl;
```

Comment: Try to explain what you want a bit clearer.  It sounds like you are passing around entity data (JSON) without a primary key, and want your saveAndFlush method to tell if if this entity already exists based on some non-pk fields.  If so, why bother using an Integer id value and instead make those fields you want to be unique the primary key?  Or you can update your saveAndFlush method to first query using the passed in fields - if the entity exists, change it based on the data passed in, otherwise merge or persist the entity.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this;

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;
```